# to display the outputs of following arithmetic operations on two numbers

Tags: python

Write a python program to display the outputs of following arithmetic operations on two numbers,which is accepted from user side ? a)Addition b)Subtraction c)Multiplication d)Division//
i wrote this code but it is not working

```
    a = int(input("Enter First Number: "))
b = int(input("Enter Second Number: "))

print("Enter which operation would you like to perform?")
 ko= input("Enter any of these char for specific operation +,-,*,/: ")

result = 0
if ko == '+':
    result = a + b
elif ko == '-':
    result = a - b
elif ko == '*':
    result = a * b
elif ko == '/':
    result = a / b
else:
    print("Error")

print(num1, ko , num2, ":", result)
```

can anybody please tell me what i did wrong or post the correct code

Comment: I can see indentation errors. Also, ```a,b``` to replace ```num1,num2``` respectively

Comment: "it is not working" is not a problem statement. Please [edit] your question and be very specific.

Comment: pls do check your indentation and could you say what error you are getting, and variables is wrong use a, b in place of num1,num2

Comment: The code you've posted won't even run because of syntax errors. Please see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) Especially the part that says **Ask about specific problems with your existing implementation.**

Answer (score 0):

The error was in your last print statement...num1 and num2 should replace as a and b.
So the last line should be:

```
print(a, ko , b, ":", result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the first line of your program isn't indented properly - You need to remove the indentation before the first line.
Here's a guide to proper indentation in python: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/indentation.html

Secondly, the variables that you call in the final print function do not exist. "num1" and "num2" aren't defined - you need to use "a" and "b", because that's what you name the return values of the input functions you call in the beginning of the program. So you can either change "num1" and "num2" to "a" and "b", or vice versa.

The final code would look something like this:

```
a = int(input("Enter First Number: "))
b = int(input("Enter Second Number: "))

print("Enter which operation would you like to perform?")
ko = input("Enter any of these char for specific operation +,-,*,/: ")

result = 0
if ko == '+':
    result = a + b
elif ko == '-':
    result = a - b
elif ko == '*':
    result = a * b
elif ko == '/':
    result = a / b
else:
    print("Error")

print(a, ko, b, ":", result)
```

Also, while programming in any language, it's advised to use descriptive names for variables - It might take some extra typing, but it will save a lot of hassle in bigger and more complex programs, and also it's a good practice.

Finally, this program (even though it gets the job done), isn't the most efficient or beginner-friendly solution for a calculator program. Here are some resources to help you understand it:

"Building a Basic Calculator | Python ": https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HBbrSDGGOkw

or, if you prefer reading:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-make-a-calculator-program-in-python-3

I'd also like to tell you that reading the error messages you get in the console would've helped you understand the problem better, and maybe even come up with a solution, but we're here to help you :)